# ITextSharp Bug? - Null reference when stamping certificate protected pdf

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using `ITextSharp's` PdfStamper to fill in a pdf form.

This works for unprotected and password protected Pdfs, but certificate protected PDFs cause a `null reference exception` when calling `PdfStamper.Close()`.

Has anyone come across this before?

Example failing program:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using X509Certificate = Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate;

namespace ITextError
{
    class Program
    {
        static X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"certificate.pfx","password",X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        static X509Certificate bouncyCertficate = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificate);
        static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(certificate.PrivateKey);

        public static byte[] CreatePdf()
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (Document document = new Document())
                {
                    var writer=PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
                    writer.SetEncryption(new X509Certificate[]{bouncyCertficate},
                                         new int[]{PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_CONTENTS},
                                         PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128
                                         ); 

                    document.Open();
                    document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static byte[] StampPdf(byte[] src)
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes("tmp.pdf",src);
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("tmp.pdf",bouncyCertficate,keyPair.Private);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms,reader.PdfVersion,true))
                {
                    PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
                    ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("Hello people!"), 36, 540, 0);
                    stamper.Close();
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }  

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"output.pdf",StampPdf(CreatePdf()));
        }
    }
}
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.CreateInfoId(Byte[] id, Boolean modified)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.GetFileID(Boolean modified)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.Close(PdfIndirectReference info, Int32 s kipInfo)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.Close(IDictionary`2 moreInfo)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper.Close()
at ITextError.Program.StampPdf(Byte[] src) in Program.cs:line 45
at ITextError.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 53
```

Exception is only thrown if the stamper is opened in append mode.
But not using append mode removes the original protection, which I need to preserve.

ITextSharp is version 5.5.4 from Nuget stable.

Comment: Please supply the stack trace and indicate the library version you are using.

Comment: Do you have the private key that corresponds with the public key that was used to protect the PDF? If not, then it's not a bug, it's a precaution. Also: you shouldn't be able to fill out a form when a file is password protected without using either the owner password or `unethicalreading`. If you are, you're using an obsolete iText version.

Comment: Edited to include failing code and stack trace.
I do have private key, But if it is a precaution, shouldn't it throw a friendlier exception?

Answer (score 0):

This iText issue has been resolved in version 5.5.12.

The relevant git check-in is d9aede3 dated March 31st, 2017, and has the comment "Fix exception when signing a document that is encrypted with certificate. Suggested by https://github.com/MADzO". This "signing" actually is a special case of arbitrary stamping while keeping the certificate protection intact.

The fix was to add the original document ID of the loaded PDF to the `PdfEncryption` object (which holds the encryption related information) in case of certificate encryption, too, not only in case of password encryption as before.

The `PdfEncryption` class expects its `documentID` member to be set as encrypted documents must have an ID. As that member was not set in the cases at hand, the `NullReferenceException` occurred.

---

<sub>Tested with the current iTextSharp 5.5.14-SNAPSHOT development version. Verified by undoing and redoing the above-mentioned fix.</sub>

<sub>Tested using [test data](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AMUB4qh_4hzNgbAU) provided by user [JC1001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6381477/jc1001) in a comment to his question [iTextSharp object reference error on PdfStamper for certificate-protected file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40045745/1729265).</sub>