# iTextSharp object reference error on PdfStamper for certificate-protected file

Tags: c#, itext

When using the PdfStamper (in append mode) to fill in a form in a certificate-protected pdf file, I get an object reference error with the following stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=itextsharp
  StackTrace:
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.CreateInfoId(Byte[] id, Boolean modified)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.GetFileID(Boolean modified)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.Close(PdfIndirectReference info, Int32 skipInfo)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.Close(IDictionary`2 moreInfo)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper.Close()
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper.Dispose()
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.TestExecute(String inputFileName, String outputFileName, String certFileName, String certPassword) in D:\Temp\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 26
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Temp\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 7
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The error was generated by the following piece of test code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestExecute(@"D:\Temp\ConsoleApplication5\Resources\CertProtected.pdf", @"D:\Temp\ConsoleApplication5\Resources\CertProtected_Filled.pdf",
                @"D:\Temp\ConsoleApplication5\Resources\John Smith.pfx", "secret");
        }

        public static void TestExecute(string inputFileName, string outputFileName, string certFileName, string certPassword)
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                var inputCertificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(certFileName, certPassword, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                var inputBouncyCertficate = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(inputCertificate);
                var inputKeyPair = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(inputCertificate.PrivateKey);
                reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(inputFileName, inputBouncyCertficate, inputKeyPair.Private);

                using (var outputStream = new System.IO.FileStream(outputFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                using (var pdfStamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, outputStream, reader.PdfVersion, true))
                {
                    var fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
                    fields.SetField("Surname", "Smith");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using iTextSharp 5.5.10 and have also tested against the latest version of the code in GitHub.  The certificate does have a private key and I can successfully open (and populate) the pdf file in Acrobat DC.  My issue looks very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897744/itextsharp-bug-null-reference-when-stamping-certificate-protected-pdf) previously logged issue, but it doesn't look like it was ever answered.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a sample certificate-protected pdf file to reproduce the issue with?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  You can find a sample [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AMUB4qh_4hzNgbAU).  Please let me know if you require anything else.

Comment: Having found your question in my ancient stack overflow favorites I just tested your code and data against a current iTextSharp. I could not reproduce the issue. So most likely the issue has been resolved somehow in the years since you posted your question.

Comment: Having found your question in my ancient stack overflow favorites I just tested your code and data against a current iTextSharp but I could not reproduce the issue. As it turned out, the bug has been fixed in 5.5.12.